unable to install npm package of griddb-node-api
I'm trying to install the griddb-node-api package for Node.js on my Windows machine, but I am running into several errors during the installation process. Here are the details:
Steps I've taken:

Installed Visual Studio Build Tools (2022 version) to ensure that I have the necessary C++ build environment.
Installed node-gyp globally using npm install -g node-gyp.
Verified Python installation (Python 3.11.9 is installed and correctly configured for node-gyp).

However, when running npm install griddb-node-api in my project folder, the installation fails with the following error:
Error Output:
enter image description here
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\Desktop\\griddb-sample-app\\node_modules\\griddb-node-api',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\Desktop\griddb-sample-app\node_modules\griddb-node-api\build'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\Desktop\\griddb-sample-app\\node_modules\\griddb-node-api\\build'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\Desktop\griddb-sample-app\node_modules\griddb-node-api
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@18.20.5 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.9 found at "C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm error gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.12.35521.163) found at:
npm error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm error gyp info spawn C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.20.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\Desktop\\griddb-sample-app\\node_modules\\griddb-node-api\\build\\config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.20.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.20.5\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.20.5',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.20.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Priyanshu Singh\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.20.5\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\Desktop\\griddb-sample-app\\node_modules\\griddb-node-api',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\Desktop\\griddb-sample-app\\node_modules\\griddb-node-api\\build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\Desktop\griddb-sample-app\node_modules\griddb-node-api) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm error gyp ERR! configure error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.5\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:297:18)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.26100
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Priyanshu Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.20.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\Desktop\griddb-sample-app\node_modules\griddb-node-api
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v18.20.5
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Priyanshu Singh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-27T05_47_22_161Z-debug-0.log

Problem:

Missing binding.gyp file: The error message suggests that binding.gyp is missing, causing the build to fail.
Permissions issues: There is a permissions issue when trying to remove certain directories during the cleanup process, possibly due to file lock or antivirus interference.
Installation fails despite required dependencies installed: I have installed the necessary dependencies like Visual Studio Build Tools, node-gyp, and Python 3.11. The problem persists.

My Environment:

Node.js version: 18.20.5
Windows version: Windows 10
Python version: 3.11.9
Visual Studio Build Tools: 2022
Docker: I am running GridDB in a Docker container on the same machine and want to connect my Node.js application to it.

Question:

Why is the installation of griddb-node-api failing, and how can I resolve the gyp: binding.gyp not found error?
How do I connect my Node.js application running on Windows to a GridDB instance running in Docker?

I've tried:

Installing all necessary build tools and dependencies.
Ensuring that Docker's network settings allow communication between the Node.js app and GridDB.
Running the npm install command as administrator, but the problem persists.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
